# How to use Countif for a string which is in separate cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, string-concatenation, countif

I need to count occurences for a particular string and it needs to be found among separated cells in two different columns. I will give you an example, can I use COUNTIF function for that?

[image: Example]

There wouldn't be a problem, but I cannot create other cells/colums to connect the string from two cells into one for this exercise purposes.

Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: So what are the desired results?

Comment: @JvdV The result should be number of occurences of the second 'ID' column. In the column 'No of Occurences' should be a formula which can compare two first colums to the fourth one and count the occurences.

Comment: Do you mean `=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$6,A2&B2)` ?

Comment: @januch please spend sometime providing the expected result, you can use share a link of the screenshot or use table markdown feature (better, check the help), otherwise you are going to get additional comments and probably not an answer because it is not clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use **countifs** instead of **countif** that accept multiple criteria.

1. Search on A column range by the first 2 characters of D column
2. Search on B column by all the other character except the first 2 characters

   =COUNTIFS(A2:A6,LEFT(D2,2),B2:B6,RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2)-2))

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, that was my expected outcome and it works perfectly. I just needed to lock A2:A6 and B2:B6 by a dollar signs. Appreciate it